# Difference between web a app and phonegap touch response

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, web-applications

I am developing a drawing app based on mrdoob harmony which is a web application drawing on html canvas.

In my web app, it detects the location of touch finger 1 and touch finger 2, and then determine the location of a cursor between them to mark the point of drawing. It works fine on most of smartphones as a web app, but after converting it into android app by PhoneGap I can find some kind of a delay in drawing.. in web app when I put two fingers touching screen the cursor appears but in the PhoneGap app the cursor and starting of drawing happens after moving my fingers and with a time delay which makes drawing hard.

What can I fix to make the PhoneGap run like the web application? Are there any code modification instead of using some kind of plugins?

Comment: As i know phonegap is mobile web touch framework , it help you development your web app faster but you can modify any content which you own. You can use java code to access and show any content on phonegap web app to where you own by div id or class name